# ajax jquery - track changes to table

Tags: jquery

Im updating a particular table with ajax using jquery every 5 seconds. I wish to highlight in yellow, any row that has been freshly inserted or changed. How do I keep track of what has changed ? Can this be done in jquery ? (My backend is django/python)

Comment: What is your code so far? `success` of ajax...

Answer (score 1):

**Some early morning coding:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myInsert = function(row){
        var $test = $('#mytest'),
            $row  = $(row),
            $tr   = $row.slice(0),
            col   = 0;

        var fade = setInterval(function(){
            $tr.css('background-color', 'rgb(255,255,'+col+')');
            if(col < 255)
               col+=5;
            else clearInterval(fade);
        }, 33);

        $test.append($row);
    };

    var newrow = '<tr><td>new1</td><td>new2</td><td>new3</td></tr>';

    $(document.body).bind('click', function(){
        myInsert(newrow); 
    });
});​
```

I guess you need to adapt some parts (I don't know how your dynamic HTML looks like). But I hope you get the general idea.

**working example**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/LrCs2/1/